# I am unable to Sign in using phone verification on Firebase using Flutter and fuurebase_auth plugin

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I keep getting this error below:
The method 'signInWithCredential' was called on null.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'signInWithCredential' was called on null.
E/flutter (29053): Receiver: null
E/flutter (29053): Tried calling: signInWithCredential(Instance of 'AuthCredential')
E/flutter (29053): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (29053): #1      _LoginScreenState._signInWithPhoneNumber (package:jollycab_flutter/screens/login_screen.dart:74:43)
E/flutter (29053): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29053): #2      _LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:jollycab_flutter/screens/login_screen.dart:384:23)
E/flutter (29053): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29053): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
E/flutter (29053): #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30)
E/flutter (29053): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24)
E/flutter (29053): #6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9)
E/flutter (29053): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:177:9)
```

I am using the code example from the flutter team here:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/example/lib/signin_page.dart

The Code starts from line 508. For some reason, signInWithCredential does not seem to be getting what it wants or is not working

Comment: hard to tell without the code, but if you used the example, then somewhere in the code you have `_auth.signInWithCredential` and _auth is null, you missing the initialization of it. or you are initializing it with invalid value (null?)

Comment: @MozesM yes sir you are correct. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for all your help. If you put it as an answer I will mark it correct.

I had:
Firebase _auth; instead of
Firebase _auth = Firebase.instance;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you used the example, then somewhere in the code you have _auth.signInWithCredential and _auth is null, you missing the initialization of it. or you are initializing it with invalid value (null?)