# Azure active directory flutter authentication issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory

My application uses Azure active directory authentication. I manage to get access token using [aad_oauth](https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth). But I am unable to sign in to firebase using that credential.

```
final Config config = Config(
  tenant: 'my_tenant',
  clientId: 'my_clientId',
  scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read/offline_access',
  redirectUri:
  'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient',
);

final AadOAuth oauth = AadOAuth(config);
await oauth.login();
String? accessToken = await oauth.getAccessToken();
final OAuthProvider oAuthProvider = OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
oAuthProvider.addScope('openid');
final OAuthCredential credential = oAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: accessToken,
);

try {
  final UserCredential authResult =
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  _updateAuthStatus(authResult);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  print('caught firebase auth exception\n ${e.code}\n ${e.message}');
} catch (e) {
  print('Error -- $e');
}
```

I am getting error message as - FLTFirebaseAuth: An error occurred while calling method Auth#signInWithCredential, errorOrNil => (null). Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please check this thread it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893875/i-am-unable-to-sign-in-using-phone-verification-on-firebase-using-flutter-and-fu

Answer (score 1):

In your provided code you have `_firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential` and `_firebaseAuth` is **null**, you are missing the initialization of it or you are initializing it with invalid value (null?)

This is how you can initialize the `FirebaseAuth` instance.

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth._instance_;
```

Please refer this [article](https://medium.com/codechai/firebase-user-authentication-using-phone-verification-in-flutter-c34dc0f7a9f8) in this it has shown how you can integrate your flutter application with FirebaseAuth.

You can refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893875/i-am-unable-to-sign-in-using-phone-verification-on-firebase-using-flutter-and-fu) thread as well the same has been also discussed over here.